# Parameters conflicting when injecting a function as an argument

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a function general enough to take any informer and any mapper and apply dependency injection for the logic not to be changed if the informer and mapper were to change, however, it seems like I am doing something wrong about my function argument generalization.

Also if I were to change unknown to any in the myFunc inform signature, it would warn me that any is not advice and is unexpected.

### Interfaces

```
interface Document {
    name: string
}
interface Mapper {
    (doc: Document): unknown
}
```

### Function

```
const myFunc = async (
    inform: (payload: unknown)=>Promise<Record<string, unknown>>,
    document: Document,
    mapper: Mapper): Promise<string> => {
  const response = <Record<string, unknown>> await inform(mapper(document));
  return response
})
```

### Problem

```
class APIClient {
   async inform(payload: RequestInfo): Promise<Record<string, unknown>> {
    // Implementation
    }
}
const apiClient = new APIClient();
const result = await myFunc(
              apiClient.inform, //Complaining that unknown cannot be assigned to RequestInfo.
              someData,
              someMapper
          );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unknown` is indeed difficult to use as a *generalization* mean.

And as you figured out, you could use `any` instead, but that removes any type safety.

You have a use case for [*generics*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), where you do not know the exact data types in advance, but you know that there must be some relations between them:

- `mapper` must take an argument type `Document2` (caution: `Document` type is already available in global scope of many environments, name collision will give unexpected result, mainly interface merging, so I will use `Document2` instead)
- It must return a type "P" (not known in advance) that `inform` can take as input.

Therefore you need at least 1 generic type ("P" above):

```
const myFunc = async <P, R>(
    inform: (payload: P) => Promise<Record<string, R>>, // inform takes P in
    document: Document2,
    mapper: (doc: Document2) => P) => { // mapper outputs P
    const response = await inform(mapper(document));
    return response
}
```

Here is an example where "P" is `string`:

```
const someData: Document2 = {
    name: 'hello'
}
const someMapper = (doc: Document2) => doc.name // Outputs a string

const result = myFunc(
    apiClient.inform, // RequestInfo is string | Request, so a string in is fine!
    someData,
    someMapper
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsEFcC2FwBMyA3gFDIXIhx4BcyAzmFKAOakC+ppC6ITyHAE8AYlhAJkAXmRwGQicgA8ABQA0yAEoA+ABTlKoGOig56ugA5whAG3RwAJvRUBKaduQqo6HMAYQlTQheKAclJhYQVg0dbQ0AenjkIxMcZDA4AGsIBk9kkAMKB0xcfDB6DGw8QjVCwTgLC2hzYoQKkuqwAjcpD1d3EmRE+sboZHQsMAtJ3JU63n4wZCgciz5-aVkAdzhgJZTTXRwGpqhdVtLwFxcAbjqVsCwoEGXV9YhObgQbOVyAQRUAEkAMI2YBlEh1OQKSQHHCWax2Rz0IIARywOTAgJAxhczm8vn8gWCJjCETYGnEmRA6C2IG0HjIlGZr0ezxIXGZXC4CwEDWAoPB4E2IAgW2QAJBYLKuluX3WSwYPggqDgGXaVTKRBkTMo1DoyAA5AALCA2OyGz68xXKgCyJzGMnOmA1ly6PQ8rQAdPqUMMAPKTaZgXJwRjMNjyxavBhYGxLGTCMQSfTM-mCspeuEJJJojFMbHGZK5clRZAAHy0EHRmI0Stk4cirHyxeQMFAEAAhHUlXhVRlaszexB7aMoKQ5UA)